# React React-router Invariant Violation: replaceState(...) Error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have started developing an app using Flux and react-router.  One of my components populates using state obtained from a Flux store.  This works fine.  However when I navigate away from this component using react-router and then back again I get the above error.  If I refresh the page the error goes away and the page works fine.

From my understanding of this it seems that react-router is not remounting this component so that it is trying to change the state of an unmounted component, hence the error.

If this is correct how do I get react-router to remount the component?

PS.  The code for this is too long to post here  It was posted on Github but since the problem has been solved now the post has been removed.
Update (thanks Sean):

The app can be run using the dist folder, just copy this folder to a webserver and point a browser to the folder (I am using xampp locally).  The problem is on the week page (component TableWeekly runs this table).  The problem occurs using the dropdown to change the view of lecturers.  Works fine when first loaded or after a refresh but fails when you navigate to another page and back again.

Comment: You may need to provide more info.  For example, which page does this happen on, how to run your code, etc?  People aren't just going to go dig through your code until they find a bug.  More details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you subscribe to change events in `componentDidMount`, but never unsubscribe on `componentWillUnmount`. In other words, every time a `TableWeekly` component is mounted, a new event handler is attached but never detached when that component unmounts.

When `MainStore` emits a change event, it will call the `_onChange` event handler on an unmounted component, which in turn will try to update state and produce an invariant error.

To fix this, add the following `componentWillUnmount` method to your `TableWeekly` and `DropdownWeekly`

```jsx
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    MainStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
}
```